# Spatie Laravel Tag query not working when loading related model

Tags: eloquent, laravel-9

Using Spatie's `withAllTags` works great in this Laravel 9 Eloquent query to retrieve all authors with books of genre `fiction`:

```
$query = Books::query();
$query->withAllTags(['fiction'], 'genre');
```

But once I load related models, it stops returning results:

```
$query = Author::query();
$query->whereHas('Books', function ($query) {
    $query->withAllTags(['fiction'], 'genre');
    });
```

This works, but the collection is upside down:

```
$query = Books::query();
$query->with('author');
$query->withAllTags(['fiction'], 'genre');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is the SQL query:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  `authors` 
where 
  exists (
    select 
      * 
    from 
      `books` 
    where 
      `authors`.`id` = `books`.`author_id` 
      and exists (
        select 
          * 
        from 
          `tags` 
          inner join `taggables` on `tags`.`id` = `taggables`.`tag_id` 
        where 
          `books`.`id` = `taggables`.`taggable_id` 
          and `taggables`.`taggable_type` = ? 
          and `tags`.`id` = ?
      )
  )
```

Comment: try dumping the generated sql query see what it actually translate to.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, need to use `withWhereHas` instead of `whereHas`:

```
$query = Author::query();
$query->withWhereHas('Books', function ($query) {
    $query->withAllTags(['fiction'], 'genre');
    });
```